# babelbib styles format first and second author names differently

Tags: bibtex, babel

I use babelbib and I have a source with two authors. Contrarily to when using the `plain` bib style, as soon as I switch to `babplain`, the author names are formatted like this:

```
[1] Müller, Jan und Eva Schulze: Name of the book, 2015.
```

While I would like both author names to be formatted the same way, that is one of these:

```
[1] Müller, Jan und Schulze, Eva: Name of the book, 2015.
[1] Jan Müller und Eva Schulze: Name of the book, 2015.
```

sources:

```
% test.tex
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{ngerman}
\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{test}

% test.bib
@manual{foo,
    author = "Müller, Jan and Schulze, Eva",
    title = "Name of the book",
    year = "2015",
}
```

I can fix it by specifying `and {Schulze, Eva}`, but that way all is treated as the last name, that cannot be the solution, can it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`babelbib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babelbib) [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/babelbib/babelbib.pdf):

> If you don’t want this behaviour you can use additional variants that use
>   the same notation for all names. By appending `-fl` to the style name, e.g.,
>   `babalpha-fl`, all names are written “Forename Lastname”. By appending `-lf`,
>   e.g., `babalpha-lf`, all names are written “Lastname, Forename”.

So use `babplain-lf` instead of `babplain` if you want

```
[1] Müller, Jan und Schulze, Eva: Name of the book, 2015.
```

or `babplain-fl` if you want

```
[1] Jan Müller und Eva Schulze: Name of the book, 2015.
```

Your example with `babplain-lf`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{ngerman}
\bibliographystyle{babplain-lf}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks! FTR: [Here is the relevant documentation](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/babelbib/babelbib.pdf)

Comment: @Marian You're welcome. P.S. Link to the documentation added in the answer.