# Wrong name separation in latex bib

Tags: bibliographies

I've found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36396/how-to-properly-write-multiple-authors-in-bibtex-file) how to write author's names in latex bib. However, the first author name is always separated in two with a comma. Here is an example:

```
@conference{ASoDToED,
title = {A Study on Deduplication Techniques over Encrypted Data},
author ={Ganesh,Amal and Sunitha,C. and Akhila,K.},
year = {2016},
booktitle = {procedia Computer Science},
volume = {87},
pages = {38 to 43}
}
```

As output i will have:

```
Ganesh, Amal, C.Sunita and K.Akhila
```

And it's the same for ALL my bibliography: the first author name is splitted with a comma. I've tried many other ways, like writing:

```
Ganesh,A. and...
Ganesh Amal and ...
```

It doesn't change anything.

However, the reference is good. For the example i gave here, the reference is [GSA16], which is the good one. So it didn't consider "Amal" as a name, but it still write it separately with a comma...
How can i get rid of this comma? It feels weird that the first name is not written as the other ones.

EDIT: Here is a minimal example. The documentclass wissdoc can be found on GIT.

```
\documentclass{wissdoc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[
    numbers,
    sort&compress
]{natbib}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion,babel=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{first Chapter}
let me introduce the chapter
~\cite{ASoDToED}
\section{first section of chapter 1}
this is my text
~\cite{SDoED}
\section{second section of chapter 1}
i have a lot of sections


\bibliographystyle{geralpha}
\bibliography{textest}
\end{document}
```

The bib file:

```
@conference{ASoDToED,
title = {A Study on Deduplication Techniques over Encrypted Data},
author ={Ganesh,Amal and Sunitha,C. and Akhila,K.},
year = {2016},
booktitle = {Procedia Computer Science},
volume = {87},
pages = {38 to 43}
}
@article{SDoED,
title={Secure Deduplication of Encrypted Data: Refined Model and New Constructions},
author={Jian, Liu and Li, Duan and Yong, Li and N., Asokan},
year={2017},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The first author is sometimes inverted, i.e. shown in "family, given" (Elk, Anne) format instead of  the "given family" (Anne Elk), because the family name is usually used to sort a name. Hence Anne Elk would be sorted under "E". It makes sense to invert the name so the "E" of "Elk" is the first thing in the entry. The other authors are then not inverted, because they don't contribute to sorting that much. In any case the order depends on the bibliography style you use. So we can only help you if you tell us which style you use in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/MWEB.

Comment: Well, it's hard to give a MWE, because i am using a documentclass and a macros file which are given to me. To gave you a MWE, i'll then have to gave you the whole files, which would make the question really long difficult to read. should i still do so?

Comment: The output is as the style defines it. If it has been given too you in a template then don't bother, obviously the template author wants it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Found that it comes from the bib, which is a ancient version of babalpha, an can be solved simply by using babalpha-fl instead.

Just be caution that geralpha comes from the package bibgerm, while babalpha comes from babelbib, so don't forget to changes the package. Plus, babelbib need babel package; german or ngerman won't be enough.

Finally, this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233432/babelbib-styles-format-first-and-second-author-names-differently)